# How to read integers more than one digit long with getchar()

Tags: c

I need to write a simple c program that **only uses getchar() and putchar()**. I understand that getchar() reads one character at a time, is there any way I can read in a number like 654 and store that into an integer array with getchar()?

Comment: Yes, of course, just call `getchar()` several times, e.g. in a loop.

Comment: When you say "store that into an array" do you mean as a *string*? Or do you want to create an array of integers, so `654` becomes one element in the array?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, sorry for not clarifying that. I mean store that entire integer into an array of integers. so I would read 654, do the conversion to integer and store into the integer array

Comment: There are two ways: Either you create a string from the individual characters and use something like `strtol` to convert it to an integer. Or you use decimal arithmetic to, in turn, create the numbers `6`, `65` and `654`. Once you have the number you store it in the desired place in the array.

Comment: Two big hints: The character `6` which `getchar` might give you, minus the character constant `'0'`, is the number 6.  And if you have the number 6, and the number 5, then 6 × 10 + 5 = 65.

Comment: thank you both, I have figured it out :)