# Is there a way to convert octal input to decimal/binary output without using math.h library and pow?

Tags: c, function, loops, math.h

Beginner programmer here.

Is there a way to input octal values and expect decimal or binary outputs without the use of functions or the math.h library? I have an idea of using a loop to achieve this but I haven't the faintest clue of how it should look like and what loop to use. I appreciate your help. Thank you.

1. stdio.h functions are allowed
2. math.h functions are not allowed

Comment: Yes, there is. Look into the [bitwise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C) operations. Actually using `pow` for this is all wrong..

Comment: When you say "library functions" what do you mean by that? What is the full and complete assignment or exercise you have? Please [edit] your question to include it, including all requirement and limitations.

Comment: Also google _octal decimal c_ and you should find what you need

Comment: As I was just saying in a comment on [a nearby question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69573936/), "The character `6`, minus the character constant `'0'`, is the number 6. And if you have the number 6, and the number 5, then 6 × 10 + 5 = 65."  That's for decimal.  To convert octal, just multiply by 8 instead of 10.  That is, 6 × 8 + 5 = 53.

Comment: Are you dealing with text input and output from a console window?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thank you so much for the advice, I'll look into that right now. I will also look into octal decimal c.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Since pow function is not permitted, or any function for that matter, as well as math.h library, I have to find a way to convert without them. The problem was, most solutions for involves a function and/or the math.h library. I will be sure to make my question complete with reqs and limitations. Thank you.

Comment: @SteveSummit I actually had that idea as well of going backwards by multiplying by 8, I just had a hard time imagining how it would look in code. Will try these solutions now. Thank you very much.

Comment: So if no "library" function is allowed, how will you read the input? How will you write the output? Again, please [edit] your question to include the full and complete assignment text, including limitations.

Comment: "stdio.h functions are allowed" So, plain `scanf` to read the ocal number into an integer variable, and use `printf` to print it as decimal?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, exactly. I need an idea of how the formula or code for conversion will look like using only stdio.h functions.

Comment: It's built into the `scanf` function, it can read octal, decimal and hexadecimal integers natively. You don't need any extra code at all, just define the variable, read it with `scanf` and print it with `printf`. Three statements in your `main` function.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

everyone. I have found a solution. I used decimal to octal code and switched values.

while loop for decimal to octal:

```
while(input){
            rem1=input%8;
            input=input/8;
            ans1=ans1+(rem1*place_value);
            place_value1=place_value1*10;
            }
```

while loop for octal to decimal:

```
while(input){
            rem1=input%10;
            input=input/10;
            ans1=ans1+(rem1*place_value);
            place_value1=place_value1*8;
            }
```

For octal to binary, simply take the answer from octal-decimal and use decimal to binary. Thank you everyone for helping.

Comment: For others seeking for help, a [example] would be much better. Oh, BTW, please adopt a code style and stick to it. Use spaces, be clear on boolean conditions, and so on.

Comment: As a beginner, I'll take note of this. Thank you.

Comment: Well, then, please [edit] your answer.